# Laplace equation over a triangle

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am very lost regarding the method of separation of variables for my PDE course. I have to solve the Laplace equation over a right triangular region, mainly:
$$u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0$$
$$u(1,y)=u(x,x)=0$$
$$u(x,0)=f(x)$$,
where $0<x<1$ and $0<y<x$. 
I have been reading some forums online ([Solving Laplace's Equation for 2D isosceles right triangle](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/solving-laplaces-equation-for-2d-isosceles-right-triangle.801583/)) in which the technique they apply has to do with considering a square region, solving the problem there, and then adding the separate solutions. Even though I know the mechanical process of solving a Laplace equation over a square, I do not understand the reasoning behind it or how to add the solutions at the end. Can someone please give me some insight?

Comment: I'm pretty sure what you need here is a change of variables to a nicer domain that you do know how to solve.